# Calculating and placing values into a second level column in a MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed DataFrame in which I want to place a level two column named AB. The values of this level two column should equal the AD[1]/DP for each Sample e.g. Sample1 AB = 60/180

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

genotype_data = [
                    ['0/1', '120,60', 180, 5, '0/1', '200,2', 202, 99],
                    ['0/1', '200,20', 60, 99, '0/1', '200,50', 250, 99],
                    ['0/1', '200,2', 202, 99, '0/1', '200,2', 202, 99] 
]


genotype_columns = [['Sample1', 'Sample2'], ['GT', 'AD', 'DP', 'GQ']]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(genotype_columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=genotype_data, columns=cols)
```

This code produces the following input file/df:

```
   Sample1                        Sample2                       
GT      AD   DP  GQ      GT      AD   DP  GQ
0/1  120,60  180   5     0/1   200,2  202  99
0/1  200,20   60   3     0/1  200,50  250  99
0/1   200,2  202  99     0/1   200,2  202  99
```

The desired result should be:

```
      Sample1                        Sample2                       
GT      AD   DP  GQ    AB      GT      AD   DP  GQ    AB
0/1  120,60  180   5  0.33     0/1   200,2  202  99  0.01
0/1  200,20   60   3  0.33     0/1  200,50  250  99  0.20
0/1   200,2  202  99  0.01     0/1   200,2  202  99  0.01
```

I have come up with a solution to this but it is pretty slow, inefficient and relies on loops. I need a much more efficient solution as I will be performing this on very big files.

```
def calc_AB(df):

    sam = df.columns.levels[0][0]
    AD = df.xs('AD', level=1, axis=1).unstack().str.split(",", n=2)
    DP = df.xs('DP', level=1, axis=1).unstack()
    AB = round(pd.to_numeric(AD.str[1]) / pd.to_numeric(DP), 2)
    df[sam, 'AB'] = AB.tolist()

    return df 


dfs = [calc_AB(df[[sam]].astype(str)) for sam in df.columns.levels[0].tolist()]

pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reorganize the indexes to make sure that there is only one column called 'AD':

```
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
stacked = df.stack()
#               AD   DP  GQ   GT    
#0 Sample1  120,60  180   5  0/1  
#  Sample2   200,2  202  99  0/1 
#1 Sample1  200,20   60  99  0/1 
#  Sample2  200,50  250  99  0/1 
#2 Sample1   200,2  202  99  0/1 
#  Sample2   200,2  202  99  0/1
```

Calculating the new column now is trivial:

```
stacked['AB'] = stacked['AD'].str.split(',').str[1].astype(int)/stacked['DP']

stacked
#               AD   DP  GQ   GT        AB
#0 Sample1  120,60  180   5  0/1  0.333333
#  Sample2   200,2  202  99  0/1  0.009901
#1 Sample1  200,20   60  99  0/1  0.333333
#  Sample2  200,50  250  99  0/1  0.200000
#2 Sample1   200,2  202  99  0/1  0.009901
#  Sample2   200,2  202  99  0/1  0.009901
```

You can restore the indexes to whatever they were before if you want.

Comment: I like this use of stack()...  And to unstack  df = stacked.stack().unstack([1,-1]).sort_index()

Comment: Surprisingly/unfortunately, this takes the same amount of time to process as my solution. However, it is much cleaner and nicer so I'll use it for now.

Comment: After further testing with vary large files, I found it is actually ~8x slower than my solution.

Comment: stack / unstack is slow for large dataframes